# Circular dependency: Magento\Backend\Helper\Data depends on Magento\Backend\Model\Url and vice versa

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I got error in magento 2 like

Circular dependency: `Magento\Backend\Helper\Data` depends on `Magento\Backend\Model\Url` and vice versa.

clearing `var/di`, `var/generation` and `var/cache` didn't help.

```
Exception #0 (LogicException): Circular dependency: Magento\Backend\Helper\Data depends on Magento\Backend\Model\Url and vice versa.
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'backendHelper', 'Magento\\Backend...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'backendUrl', 'Magento\\Backend...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'helper', 'Magento\\Backend...')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\var\generation\Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\var\generation\Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->_getSubject()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(162): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/')
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request.php(209): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->setPathInfo()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(234): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->getPathInfo()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(130): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, Array)
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-test\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#23 {main}
```

Comment: You can use Proxy to break cycle.

Comment: I am new in magento .I don't know how to use proxy